# How can you set cookies on a Selenium driver using cookies from HTTPClient's CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies, httpclient

Long story short, I'm trying to achieve some kind of hybrid web-automation. I'm making a POST request (using HTTPClient) to a website and receive the OK back, along with some cookies that get tied to the session. What I want to achieve is I want to open a page using  a Selenium driver with the cookies received from the response. I'm using the CookieContainer to store the cookies received by the requests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592617/adding-cookies-to-selenium-from-cookie-container) post and I tried to implement his solution, however I had no success.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just had to create a CookieCollection and iterate through that to add the cookies to the Selenium driver.

For anyone who is in the same situation, here's my code:

```cs
public void SetCookies() {

    CookieCollection Cookies = CookieJar.GetCookies(new Uri("https://www.example.com/"));

    foreach (System.Net.Cookie cookie in Cookies) {

        Driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value));

    }

}
```